# Making Notifier without Interval Time (with events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I made a notifier extension which checks an url like every 2-5 sec with setInterval.
Is there away to make a notifier without setInterval? Like an event which only fires if there's a change in the url or something.

I'm using jQuery to send requests to that url.

Comment: "Like an event which only fires if there's a change in the url" Which url are you talking about? window.location?

Comment: I mean if there's a change in the page of that url.

Comment: You could connect to your server using websocket.  And send messages to your client if a change occurs. But if it isn't your server, it has to provide a socket api, or you have to rely on polling.

Answer (score 0):

You must clearly define the object you want to monitor. Is it the whole page body? Is it a precise element on the page? Is it a(n) (i)frame? Is it the page url itselft? Is it an XMLHttpRequest response? Then you will [attach an event listener to that object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), if such object support event listeners (e.g. the list of supported events for [document.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLBodyElement#Properties)).

Unfortunately, the body element doesn't have an onchange element. However you can use [MutationEvents](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) which will fire when the DOM is changed but keep in mind that the support is limited and may [slow down every change in the DOM](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.platform/browse_thread/thread/2f42f1d75bb906fb).